# Вызов функции и создания массива функций

Tags: массивы, c++, функции

Предположим на вход от пользователя поступаю данные.
Если пользователь ввел "имя", то вызвать функцию name() и т.д.
Все бы ничего, если функций 1 - 5, тогда просто через if (swicth).
А вот если функций 100, тогда if-фами не удобно. Нужен цикл.

Вот моя наработка.

```
class A {
private:
int n;
void myFuncs(*[10])();
public:
A(int n_):n(n_) {
    myFuncs[0] = [n]() -> void { //хочу использовать переменную n
        //код лямбды.
    }
    ...
}
void func(int numberFunc) {
    myfuncs()[numberFunc];
}
~A() {}
}
```

Как видно в конструкторе заполняется массив функциями. Затем вызывая функцию func можно вызвать функцию из массива по индексу. К сожалению, код не работает.

Можете привести пример решения?

Comment: Вам не нужен цикл или switch. Вам нужен обычный std::map. Ключами будет ввод пользователя, значениями - ссылки на функции.

Comment: @KoVadim, я понимал... но все же как создать массив функций, или указатели на функцию в std::map в качестве value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@huxi](/users/18181/huxi), наверное самым простым решение будет написать для функции `typedef` и использовать его.

Например, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef double (*foo_t)(int a);  // вот так объявим нашу функцию

// а это пара ее конкретных реализаций
double f1 (int a) {
  cout << "f1: " << a << '\n';
  return (double)a / 10 + a;
}
double f2 (int a) {
  cout << "f2: " << a << '\n';
  return (double)a / 20 + a;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  double sum[2] = {0, 0};
  foo_t afx[2] = {f1, f2};  // массив функций

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int n = rand();
    sum[n & 1] += afx[n & 1](n); // вызовем по индексу
  }
  cout << "sum1: " << sum[0] << "  sum2: " << sum[1] << '\n';

  map<string, pair<foo_t,int> >fx; // map имя-функции : функция, индекс в sum[]
  fx["f1"] = make_pair(f1, 0);
  fx["f2"] = make_pair(f2, 1);

  map<string, pair<foo_t,int> >::iterator it;

  cout << "Now call from map\n";
  string fname;
  for (; cout << "Enter fname: ";) {
    if (!getline(cin, fname))
      break;
    if ((it = fx.find(fname)) == fx.end())
      cout << "try other fname\n";
    else // вызовем по имени
      sum[it->second.second] += it->second.first(rand());
  }
  cout << "\nNow sum1: " << sum[0] << "  sum2: " << sum[1] << '\n';
}
```

Надеюсь, понятно.

(Сведения о STL подчерпнул [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/?kw=pair))

Comment: @avp Ну настоящий садопрограммер может обойтись и без typedef'а с foo_t...
 
    double (*afx[2]) (int) = {f1, f2};  // массив функций
    map<string, pair<double (*) (int),int> >fx; // map имя-функции : функция, индекс в sum[]
    map<string, pair<double (*) (int),int> >::iterator it;